# Execute same command multiple times, changing only the value of a variable - bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm trying to run a command multiple times, changing only the value of a variable (text).

Logic would be like:

```
myvariables='test1, test2, test3'

echo "my variable is $myvariables"
```

And then it will be "executed" 3 times, changing the value of the variable...

- my variable is test1
- my variable is test2
- my variable is test3

Of course this is just an example, I do not know if it is possible.

my real code looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVER='server1'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVER > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVER is online" | echo "<h1>$SERVER is online</h1>" > $SERVER.html
else
    echo "$SERVER is offline" | echo "<h1>$SERVER is offline</h1>" > $SERVER.html
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your variables consist of single words, it can easily be done by:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVERS='server1 server2 server3' # note name in plural

for SERVER in $SERVERS; do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVER > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$SERVER is online" | echo "<h1>$SERVER is online</h1>" > $SERVER.html
    else
        echo "$SERVER if offline" | echo "<h1>$SERVER is offline</h1>" > $SERVER.html
    fi
done
```

You might want to change `$SERVER.html` into something else, if you want a single file with all the online/offline statements

Answer (score 1):

Try to use array and loop: Here I create array `$SERVERS` and run through it with `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVERS=( server1 server2 serverN )

for server in "${SERVERS[@]}"
do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $server > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$server is online" | echo "<h1>$server is online</h1>" > $server.html
    else
        echo "$server if offline" | echo "<h1>$server is offline</h1>" > $server.html
    fi
done
```

I don't understand, what means your `echo "$server is online | echo "...`.

If you need write < h1>...< /h1> in file, also print info in console, don't user pipe, write like that:

```
...
then
    echo "$server is online" 
    echo "<h1>$server is online</h1>" > $server.html
...
```